# Find age(from array(3,5,10)) from min age and max age column in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I am sending `array` of ages `[5,10,52]`. I want to search age from two columns :

1. `min_age`
2. `max_age`

Suppose i have 3 records in database(MySQL) :

1. min_age = `4`
2. max_age = `6`

---

1. min_age = `7`
2. max_age = `11`

I sent `[5,10,52]` and it should give me 2 records. `(5 and 10)`.

How can i get these records in `sequelize`. I tried with `OR` and its not working properly.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: On pure SQL you must: parse your JSON array to separate values; test each separate value against all table rows; count distinct amount of matched rows. Think how to do the same in your framework.

Comment: @Ethanolle I want to search age from `min_age` and `max_age` -> Like i give`5`and It must be Greater then `min_age` and Less than `max_age`. Did you get my point now ?

Comment: @Akina Thanks. I will check and let you know

Comment: *Like i give5and It must be Greater then min_age and Less than max_age* Strictly greater and less, not "greater or equal" and "less or equal"?

Comment: @Akina I solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this.

```
var condition = {};
var arrNew = []
if (body.ages && body.ages.length) {
    body.ages.forEach(function(age){
        arrNew.push({
            [Op.and]: [{
                'minimum_age': {
                    [Op.lte] :  parseInt(age)
                }
            }, {
                'maximum_age': {
                    [Op.gte] :  parseInt(age)
                }
            }]
        })
    })
    condition[Op.or] = arrNew                
}
```